# Styling dropdown portion for Spinner widget

Tags: android, layout, android-spinner

I don't need anything fancy, just bigger items in a list (it's too tiny) and different background. Currently it looks like so:

[image]

declaration done like this:

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/sp_serverName" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And I use code to bind items:

```
String[] items = new String[] { "Chai Latte", "Green Tea", "Black Tea" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        spinnerServerName.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerServerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of android default layout give yours like :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
```

replace with :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_item, items);
```

Comment: How is this custome_spinner_item will look like? I'm not really sure what it needs to be